# How to configure hot reload in Jhipster?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I am using Jhipster(Angular + Springboot) Application for my existing project.

I managed to create a controller(app.resource) manually apart from the ones already generated by jhiptser(using .jh file) for achieving a file download functionality.

So, when we start the server we usually initiate two servers i.e `gradlew` and `npm start`. The second runs on port 9000 which eventually supports hot reload functionality.(front-end development)

So the problem is, I am able to access those endpoints from the server running on standard 8000 port. However, from the port which is a proxy(9000), the method is returning 404.

I tried to clean build the application several times.

NOTE: The `@RequestMapping` value on the new controller is different then those present already.

Does this have to do something with spring security?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the previous controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FGAppDiagramResource {
@GetMapping(value = "/fg-app-diagram-downloadFile")
    public void getImage(String fileName,String folderName, HttpServletResponse 
    response){
    // Some Code
}
}
```

Here is my New controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fileDownload")
public class DownloadFileController {

private final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadFileController.class);


public DownloadFileController() {
    super();
}

@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties; 

@GetMapping(value = "/fg-app-diagram-downloadFile/{fileName}/{folderName}")
public void getImage(@PathVariable String fileName,@PathVariable String folderName, HttpServletResponse response) {
// Some Code
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with url of the endpoint you changed.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new controller does not use `/api` so you must add your endpoint URL `/fileDownload` to proxy configuration of webpack dev server in `webpack/webpack.dev.js`

```
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
            '/api',
            '/fileDownload',
```

You may want to use `/api/fileDownload` to avoid changing proxy configuration and also because `/api` is useful for many other aspects like security and also using HTML5 URL routing strategy in Angular to get rid of `#` in client routes (see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/9098).

`/api` and `/management` are namespaces to avoid route conflicts, so it is usually wise to use them for your new endpoints.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much for sharing the information...